# Reading mixed types from a local file

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to read a file type that has a mixture of integers, floats and strings using Javascript.

The file is drag-dropped then, with the File API, read as array buffer and wrapped with a `DataView`. That takes care of the number types but I had to make my own method for getting text.

```js
DataView.prototype.getAscii = function(byteOffset, byteLength)
{
    var bytes = new Array(byteLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
        bytes[i] = this.getUint8(byteOffset + i);
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes);
}
```

It works well enough but I worry about the speed of reading individual bytes for large files. Typed arrays can supposedly be used interchangeably with normal arrays so I tried this:

```js
DataView.prototype.getAscii = function(byteOffset, byteLength)
{
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(this.buffer, byteOffset, byteLength);
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes);
}
```

I get a "TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type" message so it doesn't like my `Uint8Array` as a parameter.

Is there a better way of reading many characters at once? [`FileReader#readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsText%28%29) reads the whole file but doesn't give access to any of the binary methods.

Comment: Can't you perhaps use `readAsBinaryString()` and then use `substr` on the string?

Comment: Good question. That's still only for getting text, there would also have to be a `readAsArrayBuffer()`. Since the files can be large and each read copies the entire file into memory I am reluctant to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slice your file with .webkitSlice/.mozSlice and then use readAsText and readAsArrayBuffer for different ranges.

Comment: I am accepting this as the best (only) answer but in practice I found my `getAscii` method and it's loop to be fast enough. Even multi-megabyte files load in an imperceptible time, less than a second and certainly faster than the accompanying network/harddisc latencies.